# Sending data such as integers and text strings from a phone to a web database

Tags: php, android, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I have a project where I'm supposed to send data such as integers, floats and text strings from an android app to a web database. However I don't have the first clue on how to do this. Could somebody shed some light on this please??? Any advise or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

1. You need program some server-side logic (PHP page that accepting parameters key=value by POST or GET method)
2. Then if data is verified save it to the database
3. In phone you must implement HttpClient and HttpPost classes to POST this data to PHP page

In phone you can use following code (no tested):

```
    public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "Hi"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

In PHP you can do something like this:

```
<?php
//Check whether the data has been submitted
if (isset($_POST['id'] && isset($_POST['stringdata'])) ) {

   //Let's now print out the received values in the browser
   echo "Id: {$_POST['id']}<br />";
   echo "String data: {$_POST['stringdata']}<br />";

   //you can implement database logic here too (insert data to database)
} else {
    echo "You can't see this page without submitting the data.";
}
?>
```

Comment: @ evilone - Thanks for this advice, really appreciated it. Is it to xml to create web service at all? (Sorry if this seems to be a stupid question but this is my first time trying something like this out.)

Comment: If you want to learn about web services, you can start learning from wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service But you may also create XML or JSON on the phone and send file over the network. There's multiple solutions to do this. What I posted, is maybe the simplest way to start exploring this world :)

Comment: @ evilone - Thanks for the advice and thank you especially for the sample code. I'll try it and tell you how it goes. And thanks for telling me about the different options :)

Comment: Also try to remember that Google is you friend :) Try searching "Android+webservice" or "Android+REST" and internet is full of examples...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on soap 
(on android you can use the ksoap2 package)
you cen also create a socket connection to o program on the server side

Comment: Thanks sherif, but what are the soap and ksoap2 package? Could you explain?