# How can I upload files from Android using HTTP POST?

Tags: android, android-emulator

everyone. I have a project where I have to upload files to the apache web server that is on my laptop. I have heard about HTTPPOST and HTTPGET in php, but I am not sure as to how it works with respect to file uploads. Can somebody please explain? I am using the android emulator to try and do this for the time being and any help would be appreciated very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post multipart request with Android SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017414/post-multipart-request-with-android-sdk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381146/sending-data-such-as-integers-and-text-strings-from-a-phone-to-a-web-database/5381217#5381217)

Comment: @ :) Thanks, I just wanted to know how would it be different from the sample code u gave me.