# Android facebook image uploading?

Tags: android

I have below code to upload photo...

```
            byte[] data = null;

            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL("http://aux.iconpedia.netuploads/250578763.png");
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            data = baos.toByteArray();

            params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
            params.putByteArray("picture", data);
```

Logcat is ::

```
11-04 22:48:57.535: WARN/Bundle(424): Key picture expected String but value was a [B.  The default value <null> was returned.
11-04 22:48:57.555: WARN/Bundle(424): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
11-04 22:48:57.555: WARN/Bundle(424): java.lang.ClassCastException: [B
11-04 22:48:57.555: WARN/Bundle(424):     at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1040)
11-04 22:48:57.555: WARN/Bundle(424):     at com.logistics.finalfacebook.Util.encodeUrl(Util.java:85)
11-04 22:48:57.555: WARN/Bundle(424):     at com.logistics.finalfacebook.Facebook.dialog(Facebook.java:622)
11-04 22:48:57.555: WARN/System.err(424): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-04 22:48:57.565: WARN/System.err(424):     at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:53)
11-04 22:48:57.565: WARN/System.err(424):     at com.logistics.finalfacebook.Util.encodeUrl(Util.java:85)
11-04 22:48:57.565: WARN/System.err(424):     at com.logistics.finalfacebook.Facebook.dialog(Facebook.java:622)
11-04 22:48:57.565: WARN/System.err(424):     at com.logistics.finalfacebook.MainActivity$LoginDialogListener.onComplete(MainActivity.java:245)
11-04 22:48:57.565: WARN/System.err(424):     at com.logistics.finalfacebook.Facebook$1.onComplete(Facebook.java:316)
11-04 22:48:57.565: WARN/System.err(424):     at com.logistics.finalfacebook.FbDialog$FbWebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(FbDialog.java:134)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to do an upload to Facebook. And your Logcat appears to be during Facebook authorize(). Do you need to put up more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Facebook.java` on line 622, your are calling `Util.java`'s `encodeUrl()` with a null string.

This is how you use it :

```
try {
    String url = "http://www.example.com/?id=123&art=abc";
    String encodedurl = URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");
    Log.d("TEST", encodedurl);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @Reno.. i have image from sdcard and how to do for it>

Comment: How to do what for what? If you are asking how to do an upload for using HTTP post , [here is your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381146/sending-data-such-as-integers-and-text-strings-from-a-phone-to-a-web-database/5381217#5381217)

Comment: i have image in sdcard i want to share it facebook how?

Comment: You'll need the android facebook sdk for that, [here is an example of how to upload a file](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/examples/simple/src/com/facebook/android/Example.java)